# ethermint: command not found, When attempting ethermint installation?

Tags: currency, blockchain, ethereum, tendermint

I'm following the steps to install ethermint on top of tendermint that are listed on the README on this github page: https://github.com/tendermint/ethermint, but at the step `ethermint --datadir ~/.ethermint init setup/genesis.json`, then I get the following error: `ethermint: command not found`

And yes, I installed tendermint previous to my attempted installation of ethermint.

Comment: relevant github issue: https://github.com/tendermint/ethermint/issues/212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solution I figured out for my problem is contained on the GitHub issue page linked above, I also wanted to include it here for the sake of people who have the same issue.

> OK, so I fixed the problem, and it was so infuriating. It turns out
>   that whenever I opened a terminal, then the go version would default
>   to go1.6, even if I was in the go1.8.3 directory. To solve the error,
>   you need to delete the old go version off of your computer, and then
>   use gvm to set the right go version. Thanks to everyone who helped me
>   solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your current directory:

`ls`

if ethermint doesn't exist you need to install it again